# Javascript convert value from cookie to object

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a cookie and its name is persons and the value is the following:

`{"person":"Will","color":"Blue"}`

How would I put this value into an object or create an object with this?

I got this:

```
var cookie = document.cookie.valueOf("persons");
var cookieSplit = cookie.split(';');
var finalSplit = cookieSplit[1].split('=');
var persons = [];
var persons = finalSplit[1];

console.log(persons);
```

but this returns:

`{"person":"Will","color":"Blue"}` with no Object infront of it, which I am expecting, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value appears to be formatted as JSON, so [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) could probably be used:

```
var persons = JSON.parse(finalSplit[1]);

console.log(persons);
// Object { person: 'Will', color: 'Blue' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to parse it as JSON? It's being stored as string.

```
JSON.parse(persons);
```